# In hardware level, how to reset bios in windows tablets?

Tags: windows, bios

I have i-life zedbook tablet, I disabled an usb option related to enabling usb3 -as I remember-. Now the tablet doesn't recognize the keyboard  **even** in booting, I could find a way to enter to bios menu by pressing volume + , - and power together to turn on the tablet, however I couldn't choose and select.
what I need to know is that if the bios data is stored in rom (like computers)and how to cut the current to it! I tried to remove the tablet battery, but not working.
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Press the Volume +  Press the Power Button then hold them both until the System Menu appears on the Upper left corner of the screen.

hope that helps

Comment: thank you, but i can't use touch screen,So I need a way to do something in the mainboard of the tab to reset the bios without turning the tab on